# How to use infoBox/ valueBox within flexdashboard

Tags: r

Hi I was wondering is there a way to use infoBox(), valueBox() or any other similar visuals with flexdashboard with runtime shiny? The goal is to have a box that shows summarized values for my dashboard.

```
---
title: "Old Faithful Eruptions"
output: flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
runtime: shiny
---
```